# SQL Multiple Entry Syntax

Tags: sql, select

I'm having trouble finding out the proper syntax for selecting from a table all entries that have a multiple occurrence, and was hoping somebody would be able to point me in the right direction.

This IS homework, so please answer it in a way that abides by the rules and doesn't make me a cheater. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` whatever defines a row having multiple occurrence, then select only those `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM theTable
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```